# each function index and element

Tags: javascript, jquery

my question is a simple one how do you use element with index in each function

```
$('div').each(function(index, element) {
     is element equal to $(this)
});
```

Comment: Your question might be simple if you added more details. Please add more details on what you're trying to do

Comment: The answer might be as simple as $(this)

Comment: Ascii what you did there. But yeah - more info..?

Comment: how do u use element in the collection there is no documentation about it

Comment: Try to give more information so that we are clear to answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `element` there will *always* be the same as `this`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/7Jhv8/).

Except wrapping it in `$()` will make it a jQuery object, and won't be equal to the other one, even if you wrap the other with a jQuery object.

There should never be a reason why you need to compare `this` to `element` in that context.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('div').each(function(index, element) {
     //element != $(this)
     //element == this
});
```

`$(this)` is `this` wrapped by a jquery object. So while `this` won't equal `$(this)`, you can still manipulate it to your heart's content

Here's something to look at : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/ZqXPn/